# How to std::merge two std::vector in-place?

Tags: c++, vector, merge

Following code attempts to `std::merge` `v2` into `v1`.

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,0,0,0};
std::vector<int> v2{1,2,3};

std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + 3, v2.begin(), v2.end(), v1.begin());

for (auto i : v1)
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

The expected output is: `1 1 2 2 3 3`

The actual output by this code is : `1 1 1 1 2 3`

A potential fix for this problem, is to create a temporary vector.

```cpp
std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,0,0,0};
std::vector<int> v2{1,2,3};

std::vector<int> tmp(v1.size());

std::merge(v1.begin(), v1.begin() + 3, v2.begin(), v2.end(), tmp.begin());

for (auto i : tmp)
{
    std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

I want to avoid this memory overhead and do it in-place in vector `v1`.
Any idea how I can do that with `std::merge`?

Comment: I would say you can no merge inplace in linear time, it would always need many array shift operations.

Comment: `std::merge` expects destination range doesn't overlap with either of the input ranges

Answer (score 1):

Checking [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) reference:

> The behavior is undefined if the destination range overlaps either of the input ranges (the input ranges may overlap each other).

Thus, you can't use `std::merge` for in-place merging. Try writing a merge function and you will know why.